# how to append variable inside the hx-delete?

Tags: spring-boot, htmx, spring-thymeleaf

I currently have a springboot app with thymeleaf, now I'm trying to use HTMX.
Now in my table, each row has a delete button.

```
 <tr th:each="training : ${trainings}">
     <th scope="row">[[${training.id}]]</th>
     <td> <a class="btn-delete"  hx-delete="/delete/${training.id}"> </a>
 </tr>
```

On hx-delete, it cant detect the `${training.id}`.
I tried this but still not working

`hx-delete="|/delete/${training.id}|"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal HTML attributes do not have access to Thymeleaf bindings. To solve this we can use the [default attribute processor](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#setting-the-value-of-any-attribute-default-attribute-processor).

> ### 5.6 Setting the value of any attribute (default attribute processor)
>
> Thymeleaf offers a *default attribute processor* that allows us to set the value of *any* attribute, even if no specific `th:*` processor has been defined for it at the Standard Dialect.
>
> So something like:
>
> ```html
> <span th:whatever="${user.name}">...</span>
> ```
>
> Will result in:
>
> ```html
> <span whatever="John Apricot">...</span>
> ```

To pass a dynamic URL we'll have to combine this with the [URL rules](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#link-urls).

Resulting in the following code:

```html
<a th:hx-delete="@{/delete/{id}(id=${training.id})}"></a>
```

Assuming `training.id` is `1`, this should produce:

```html
<a hx-delete="/delete/1"></a>
```

---

ps. Using `delete` in the path seems unnecessary, since the *HTTP method* already signifies the same. A more logical route would be `DELETE /trainings/:id`.

```html
<a th:hx-delete="@{/trainings/{id}(id=${training.id})}"></a>
```

Comment: It's working now. Thank you!